# FAQs as discussion items

Tags: discussion, comments, meta-faq, canonical

The presence of lengthy and contentious debates on FAQ questions here is confusing. I note in particular [the FAQ on community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11747#11747). Shog9 tried to help this with a link in his answer, but the link is broken. If something is a real, accept-no-substitutes, FAQ, I think that discussions should be ruthlessly removed by moderators.

Comment: I had to go look up FTFY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. That FAQ in particular has been a steaming pile of time-wasting discussion for far too long... Whatever purpose such ranting might once have had on a FAQ question, it's long ago disappeared.

So I just used up all my flags for the day requesting moderator deletion, and I encourage you to do likewise.